# No premake script(premake5.lua) found error

Tags: visual-studio, box2d, command-prompt, premake

This is my first posted question so sorry for any mistakes I make. I recently was trying to setup Box2D on visual studio 2017 and I was told that you must use premake5 to first create the sample project and then you can begin using Box2D. The problem is that when I call `premake5 vs2017 Downloads/Box2D-master/Box2D-master/Box2/premake5.lua` in command prompt (I have also tried with vs2015 and vs2013 ), the program throws an error `No Premake script (premake5.lua) found!`. I have triple checked file paths but nothing seems to be working. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I think @starkos is correct, it isn't a matter of your `paths being correct` but rather `are you in the correct path`.  Navigate to where the `premake5.lua` file is first, then run `premake5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/erincatto/Box2D.git
$ cd Box2D/Box2D
$ premake5 vs2017
```